# Are module imports treated differently by vite in development and production?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I am attempting to import a library (jointjs) into a Vue app. It gets assigned as a global property on Vue and subsequently modified. Here's a simple reproduction of what I'm trying to do:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import * as joint from 'jointjs';
import App from '@/App.vue';

// we need to get our own connectors
let customConnectors={
    f: function() {}
}

Vue.use({
    install: function (Vue) {
        // In development, this works:
        //    _.assign(joint.connectors, customConnectors);
        // as does this:
        //    _.each(customConnectors, (item, key) => { joint.connectors[key] = item;});
        // and this:
        //    for (const connector in customConnectors) {
        //       joint.connectors[connector] = customConnectors[connector];
        //     }
        // but none of those work in production, saying joint is a constant or not extensible
                // this one gives a build error about f not being exported by jointjs/src/connectors
                //    joint.connectors['f'] = customConnectors['f'];
        // this one gives the same error but runs without error; but only when minified, so I think it's actually
                //    just removing the statement 
                joint.connectors.f = customConnectors.f; 
        Vue.joint = joint;
    }
});

let app = new Vue({
  joint,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Every one of the examples in the comments above works fine in dev. None of them work when built for production.

The problem seems to be in production the import of jointjs is treated as a const but in development it's not?

This is my vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { createVuePlugin } from 'vite-plugin-vue2';
import ViteComponents from 'vite-plugin-components';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [ 
      createVuePlugin(), 
      ViteComponents({
      })
    ],
  server: {
    port: 8080
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: '@',
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      }
    ]
  },
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 600,
  }
});
```

Is this intentional behavior? Is there a build option I'm missing?

Here's a reproduction repo if it's helpful: https://github.com/dovrosenberg/vite-test

Thanks!

Comment: *is a constant or not extensible* - this means that `joint.connectors` is module object, they cannot be modified by specs, so you can't do what you're trying to do. It's expected that dev and prod modes behave differently in any setup due to differences between them (hot reload, minification, etc), including the way modules are handled.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. I can confirm that joint and joint.connectors are both module objects. But this is the documented way to add custom functionality to the object (see https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.4/joint.html#connectors.custom for one example but there are many others in the docs and throughout stackoverflow).  Is there a vite build option to treat the module the same in prod as it does in dev?  Should I clone the object somehow (it's very deep, so not sure how practical that is)?

Comment: This mean that there's a mistake in a way the library was written, `joint.connectors` isn't supposed to be modified in a way the docs suggest, consider opening an issue. I'm not sure if a lib can be easily extended to allow this, this depends on how exactly it uses `connectors`. If it imports the object directly, this would require to fork the lib. The link also says, "or passed directly as a function to the connector property", which is probably a proper option. here.

Comment: Generally you'd need to transform ES module to CommonJS or UMD before bundling to suppress spec-compliant behaviour. I don't use Vite a lot and can't say if this can be easily achieved there because it heavily favours ESM. Probably something like https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/174#issuecomment-630350668

Comment: The function approach has other issues, as then objects that use the connector can't be serialized properly.  But that link looks super helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hints from Estus Flask in the comments, I've managed to make this work.

I used rollup to convert jointjs to an ES module first.

`npm i --save-dev rollup-plugin-commonjs`

Rollup should already be installed because vite uses it.

I created a rollup.config.js file in the project root:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: 'node_modules/jointjs/joint.mjs',
  output: {
    file: 'src/plugins/jointjsESM.js',
    format: 'es',
    freeze: false,  // this is key to preventing everything from being constant
  },
  plugins: [
    commonjs({
      // search for files other than .js files (must already
      // be transpiled by a previous plugin!)
      extensions: [ '.js', '.mjs' ],  // Default: [ '.js' ]

      // if true then uses of `global` won't be dealt with by this plugin
      ignoreGlobal: false,  // Default: false

      // if false then skip sourceMap generation for CommonJS modules
      sourceMap: false,  // Default: true
    }),
  ],
};
```

The `output.file` value can point to wherever you want the resulting module to be.

You can then create package.json script (or use npx) to run `rollup --config rollup.config.js`

That will create the new module file at the output.file location.  You could run this script before vite build as part of a build pipeline.

Then, instead of `import * as joint from 'jointjs'`, you import from the file that was output, but you need to assemble the joint object yourself using whichever pieces you need... for example:

```
import {
   g,
   dia,
   shapes,
   connectors,
} from '@/plugins/jointjsESM.js';

let joint = { g, dia, shapes, connectors};
```

You can also move jointjs to only be installed as a dev dependency since it's not being used as part of the build.